# Combine, compare, and order a list in a certain order

Tags: python, list

```
list1 = [-1, 2, -3]
list2 = [4, -6, 3]
print(get_negatives_at_front(list1, list2))
print()
list1 = [1, 2, -3, 4, 7]
list2 = [4, -6, 3, -1]
print(get_negatives_at_front(list1, list2))
```

Prints

```
[-1, -6, -3, 3, 2, 4]
[-6, -3, -1, 7, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1]
```

I am not sure as to how I should go about this question. My first attempt involved me making a new list and just ordering it:

```
list3 = list1 + [i for i in list2 if i not in list1]
list3 = sorted(list3)
return list3
```

But this is not what is expected from the question. I think we need to use:

```
for number in list1:
    if number < 0:
```

But I can't figure out what to do.

Comment: From the problem statement, `get_neagatives_at_front` seems to do just fine?

Comment: `get_negatives_at_front` is the function we are trying to make

Comment: Are you allowed to use `sorted`? `sorted(list1+list2)` or `sorted(list1+list2, key= lambda x: x > 0)`

Comment: I tried using `sorted` but it didn't match up the answer with what was required. Appending the negatives to a new list and positives to another list, and then combining the two and reversing the positive list using `[::-1]`  did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is helopful. thanks.

```
def get_negatives_at_front(list1, list2):
   a = max(len(list2), len(list1))
   ### Make the length of lists equal by adding NONE item
   if len(list1) > len(list2):
      for d in range(0, len(list1) - len(list2)):
         list2.append(None)
   elif len(list2) > len(list1):
      for d in range(0, len(list2) - len(list1)):
         list1.append(None)
   ### add negative & positive items in two seperate lists while iterating
   neg = []
   pos = []
   for l in range(0, a):
     print l
     if list1[l] != None: ###Ignore none items which was added to make length equal to the other list
        if list1[l] < 0:
           neg.append(list1[l])
        else:
           pos.append(list1[l])
     if list2[l] != None:
        if list2[l] < 0:
           neg.append(list2[l])
        else:
           pos.append(list2[l])
   print neg+pos   ### join two lists

list1 = [1, 2, -3, 4, 7]
list2 = [4, -6, 3, -1]
print(get_negatives_at_front(list1, list2))
```

Comment: you should do `a = max(len(list2), len(list1))` in case list1 is the longest one

Comment: Thank you. I was having issues with the function appending if list1 had more characters - but that max has fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use a Python library, then the [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) function could be used to read off the elements from your two lists in order as follows:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def get_negatives_at_front(list1, list2):
    pos = []
    neg = []

    for v1, v2 in zip_longest(list1, list2):
        if v1 is not None:
            neg.append(v1) if v1 < 0 else pos.append(v1)
        if v2 is not None:
            neg.append(v2) if v2 < 0 else pos.append(v2)

    return neg + pos

list1 = [-1, 2, -3, 0]
list2 = [4, -6, 3]

print(get_negatives_at_front(list1, list2))
```

This would display the following output:

```
[-1, -6, -3, 4, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

For an easy way according to your scenario

```
def get_negatives_at_front(list1, list2):
    lp, ln = [], []
    for i in range(len(list1) if len(list1) >= len(list2) else len(list2)):
        if i < len(list1): ln.append(list1[i]) if list1[i] < 0 else lp.insert(0, list1[i])
        if i < len(list2): ln.append(list2[i]) if list2[i] < 0 else lp.insert(0, list2[i])
    return ln + lp

get_negatives_at_front([-1, 2, -3], [4, -6, 3])
> [-1, -6, -3, 3, 2, 4]

get_negatives_at_front([1, 2, -3, 4, 7], [4, -6, 3, -1])
> [-6, -3, -1, 7, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1]
```

Comment: `.insert` is really inefficient. This scales horribly.

Comment: So perhaps use `.append` and do a reverse `lp[::-1]` will be better?

Comment: As i understood OP, the ordering of the positives and negatives is irrelevant. As long as they are separated it should be good. So just using append with no reversing should be enough.

Comment: yeah, the only reason of `.insert` is to fit the answer @Nume wants. Thx for the reminder of inefficient of `.insert`.

Comment: Ahh, well if he wanted the negatives in the order they appear in the input, and the positives in reverse. I think it would scale better to reverse the positives afterwards like you suggested,

Comment: "if it is a positive number, it is inserted in the next available position going down from the end of the list to be returned." from this i would assume using `append` would be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to use `zip` to create a pair of elements from the two lists. Since the length of the lists can be arbitrary and may not match, the best is to use `izip_longest` from itertools, which though would "pad" missing elements with `None` by default. Then we just perform the checks and use two auxiliary lists (positives,negatives) and depending on the value we are iterating upon we either append it to the end of the negatives list, or push at the front of the positives one, then concatenate the two before outputting it. In code:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def get_negatives_at_front(l1, l2):
    negatives = []
    positives = []
    # This will alternate on elements from list1,list2:
    # In case of padding needed, this will put "None"
    for x,y in izip_longest(l1, l2):
        # check if not None
        if x is not None:
            negatives.append(x) if x < 0 else positives.append(x)
        if y is not None:
            negatives.append(y) if y < 0 else positives.append(y)

    # concat the two lists after reversing the positives list
    return negatives+list(reversed(positives))

list1 = [-1, 2, -3]
list2 = [4, -6, 3]
print get_negatives_at_front(list1, list2)
```

This will give you the result of:

```
[-1, -6, -3, 3, 2, 4]
```

Also see it in action at:
https://eval.in/509593

Comment: Swapping `positivites.insert` with `positives.append` whill make this scale a lot better.

Comment: @M4rtini Agreed on the speed/scale, but had to use that to respect the order of the request. Using positives.append and then reverting the list at the end before the return is likely the best. Thanks for noting.

Answer (score 0):

Using [chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)  and [deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

```
from collections import deque 
from itertools import chain

def get_negatives_at_front(l1, l2):
    res = deque()
    for i in chain(l1, l2):
        if i < 0:
            res.appendleft(i)
        else:
            res.append(i)
    return list(res)
```

comparing timings of other answers:

```
list1 = [random.randint(-100, 100) for _ in range(100000)]
list2 = [random.randint(-100, 100) for _ in range(100000)]

%timeit get_negatives_at_front(list1, list2) 
# 10 loops, best of 3: 42 ms per loop

%timeit get_negatives_at_front_Rick(list1, list2)
#1 loops, best of 3: 5.85 s per loop

%timeit get_negatives_at_front_Trying2Learn(list1, list2)
#10 loops, best of 3: 89.8 ms per loop

%timeit get_negatives_at_front_Sal(list1, list2)
#1 loops, best of 3: 5.72 s per loop

%timeit get_negatives_at_front_martin_evans(list1, list2)
#10 loops, best of 3: 52.9 ms per loop

#%timeit get_negatives_at_front_Minitoto(list1, list2)
#Does not work in python 3
```

**Edit:**
Initially OP's question contained this description of the return value for the function

> The function returns a new list containing all the elements from both
>   the parameter lists with all the negative numbers at the front of the
>   list and all the positive numbers at the back of the list.

I took from this that the internal ordering of the positives and negatives was not important. So this only makes sure the negatives precedes the positives.

So for the sample input it gives: `[-6, -3, -1, 2, 4, 3]` instead of `[-1, -6, -3, 3, 2, 4]`

Comment: Kudos on the speed. Can you check it though? Seems like your function is not returning the expected result. What I get is `[-6, -3, -1, 2, 4, 3]`.

https://eval.in/509166

Comment: @sal You're correct, i did not get that the order was important. I thought it was ok, as long as the negatives came first. The assignment text did not mention this as far as i could see.  See my last edit

Comment: Actually I just noticed you commented on this same somewhere else in this long thread. I learned something in the process. :-)